# how could get {{a.b}} work in angular

Tags: angular

I am newbie with typescript and angularjs.

1.in file app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements Oninit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  a = {"hello":"world", "nice": "day"};
  b = "hello";
  c = "nice";
  d : string;

 ngOnInit(): void{ 
   this.d = this.b;  //or this.d = this.c;
 }
}
```

2.in app.component.html

```
{{a.b}}  // actually i want it print "world" or "day"
```

how could i make {{a.b}} print "world" ?

ANSWERED by "vishnu s pillai" and "Muhammed Albarmawi":
object['propertyName'] can use var 
so {{a[b]}} is the answer

Comment: Consider reading th documentation (and learning Javascript) before posting this kind of question. `{{ a.hello }}`.

Comment: and is better to change the declaration of a to a = { hello: "world"}

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: i know {{a.hello}}  works. but the b is a var not static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can access to any object property by `object.propertyName` or bracket notation like this `object['propertyName']`

In your app.component.html just write like this `{{a[b]}}` or `{{a.hello}}`

read more about [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {"hello":"world"};
b = "hello";
{{a.b}} // undefined
{{a[b]}} //world
```

if you want to use variables to point object keys in the html then use bracket notation.

so you should use {{a[b]}} insted of {{a.b}}